# CSS Flexbox layout with unknown child height 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a problem with what I assumed would be a relatively simple CSS layout.

I want...

- a footer at the bottom (fixed height)
- a nav bar on the left side (fixed width)
- an outer content pane on the right side (dynamic size)

And in the content pane...

- a ribbon on the top (fixed height)
- an inner content div (dynamic size)

I'm trying to use flexbox for this, as it seems to be the best option at present (grid is too unstable and not well supported).

The problem is that my inner content div is (in reality) several layers deep inside the outer content div. This means I cannot be using flexbox directly on it, as flex is a direct parent-child relationship (and I'm a few layers deep, as per the comment in the code).

Ideally I want to do it as my below code, however as you can see, the inner div is flowing OUTSIDE the containing outer div's box, behind the footer, and then outside the entire container (for the height of the ribbon div).

It would seem "height: 100%" just does not deal with it properly... but I can't have every item in the chain from "content" to "inner" set up with flexbox - as I literally do not have control over this. (I'm using angular, and it generates a bunch of  tags every layer, and they're dynamically named).

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%
}

.body {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.content {
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1;
}

.ribbon {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 99px;
}

.inner {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    background-color: lime;
    flex: 0 0 38px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="ribbon">STUFF<br>BLAH</div>
            <!-- there is actually a bunch of other stuff in between "content" and "inner"-->
            <div class="inner">
            

content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>

</body>
```

I have made a plunker to demonstrate the problem...

https://plnkr.co/edit/zzFHhLK7nef1VNQkwp7U?p=preview

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I recommend is making a **second** layer of flexbox, by adding `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to `.content`, in addition to its existing `flex: 1`:

```
.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Considering flexbox is a parent-child relationship, you'll need to add `flex: 1` to anything that is a **direct child** of `.content`, which can be done by using the **[child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** `>`:

```
.content > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

In addition to this, you'll need to set a **max-height** on the `.ribbon`:

```
.ribbon {
  max-height: 99px;
}
```

Combined together, this can be seen working in the following example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content > * {
  flex: 1;
}

.ribbon {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 99px;
  max-height: 99px;
}

.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lime;
  flex: 0 0 38px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="ribbon">STUFF<br>BLAH</div>
        <!-- there is actually a bunch of other stuff in between "content" and "inner"-->
        <div class="inner">
          content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> content
          <br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, this gave me what I needed to get the layout working :D
The child combinator was a great idea - solved the problem of my "unknown layer" in between... .content > *:not(router-outlet)